# Regex to match string with contains closed brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, match

I need to create regex rule to match string with doesnt' contain `(` `)` character and also strings that have them inside but always closed (but not nested. Another thing that empty `()` is also wrong

Good strings (should be matched):

```
aaaaaa
(asdasd)
aaaa(bbb)a
(aaa)aaaa
aaaaaa(aaaa)
aaaa(bbb)(ccc)ddd
aaaa(bbbb)cccc(dddd)eeee
```

Bad strings (there shouldn't be match):

```
)aaaa
)aaaa(asd)
aaaaaa(
aaaa(bbb))
aaa(bbb
aaaaa((bbbb)cccc
aaaa(bbbb))ccc
aaaa(aasd(adssad))ad
adassd(aas(add)adsa(asda)ad)
()
```

Tried and created something like this `(?!.*[(]{2,})(?!.*[)]{2,})(?![)])(?!.*[(]$).*$` but still it isn't good. Any help with this?

Comment: How many levels there could be? Is this a good string or a bad one: `aaa(bb(cc)bb)`?

Comment: One level of parentheses is attainable and practical. A fixed number of levels is attainable but not practical with more than a few levels. Arbitrary nesting is not a regular language any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex for your job:

```
/^(?!$)(?:[^)(]*\([^()]+\))*[^)(]*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJhNj9/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^` - Line start
- `(?!$)` - Negative lookahead to make sure we don't match empty string
- `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group

  - `[^)(]*` - Match 0 or more of anything but `(` and `)`
  - `\(` - Match a `(`
  - `[^()]+` - Match 1 or more of anything but `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - Match a literal `)`
- `)*` - End of the non-capturing group, `*` makes it match `0` or more times
- `[^)(]*`- Match 0 or more of anything but `(` and `)`
- `$` - Line end

Comment: Unnecessarily convoluted and verbose, no need to match `[^)(]` twice.

Comment: @georg: It might look longish but it will be more efficient than `^([^()]|\([^()]+\))+$` (you can check # of steps taken on regex101)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for balanced parens, you can use a function like this:

```js
function balanced(str) {
  var a = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {  // for each character in str
    if(str.charAt(i) == '(') a++;        // if it's an open paren, increment a
    else if(str.charAt(i) == ')') a--;   // if it's a close one, decrement a
  }
  return a == 0;                         // if a == 0 then it's balanced (true), if not then it's not balanced (false)
}

var s1 = "aaaa(bbbb)cccc(dddd)eeee";
var s2 = "aaaa(bbbb(cccc(dddd)eeee";
var s3 = "aaaa";

console.log(s1 + " => " + balanced(s1));
console.log(s2 + " => " + balanced(s2));
console.log(s3 + " => " + balanced(s3));
```

Or if you insist on using regexp, then use two regexp to check for balanced parens like this:

```js
function balanced(str) {
  var opened = str.match(/\(/g);      // match open parens
  var closed = str.match(/\)/g);      // match close parens
  opened = opened? opened.length: 0;  // get the count of opened parens, if nothing is matched then 0
  closed = closed? closed.length: 0;  // get the count of closed parens, if nothing is matched then 0
  return opened == closed;            // balanced means the count of both is equal
}

var s1 = "aaaa(bbbb)cccc(dddd)eeee";
var s2 = "aaaa(bbbb(cccc(dddd)eeee";
var s3 = "aaaa";

console.log(s1 + " => " + balanced(s1));
console.log(s2 + " => " + balanced(s2));
console.log(s3 + " => " + balanced(s3));
```

Comment: You might want to check your function with `")))x((("`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
^([^()]|\([^()]+\))+$
```

reads "match not a paren or ( no parens here ), once or more, whole string"

If you want to match balanced parens at any level, a single expression is not possible in js, due to lack of recursion support, but a function will be rather trivial.

```js
let balanced = function(s) {
  var re = /\([^()]*\)/g
  while (s.match(re)) s = s.replace(re, '')
  return !s.match(/[()]/)
}

console.log(balanced('a(b((d))e) (f) g'))
console.log(balanced('a(b((d))e? (f) g'))
```

or without regexes:

```js
let balanced = s => {

    let c = 0;

    for (let x of s) {
        if (x == '(') c++;
        if (x == ')' && !c--) return false;
    }

    return !c;
};
```